# Mock an API url in WebDriver in an e2e test

Tags: angular, npm, webdriver, e2e

I have the following code:

```
import {ListPage} from "../../page/list.page";

describe("ListComponent", () => {
  //Given
  beforeEach(async () => {
    
    await browser.mock("**/wdr/prices");
    await ListPage.open();

  });

  it("should render a list", async () => {
    //When
    const tableRows = await ListPage.getTableAsTextArray();

    console.log(tableRows);
    //Then
    expect(tableRows.length).toEqual(3);
  });

});
```

When I run:

```
npm run e2e
```

I get this error:

```
error properties: Object({ input: '/json/version', code: 'ERR_INVALID_URL' })
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:405:5)
    at new URL (node:internal/url:611:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async UserContext.<anonymous>
```

the browser is a WebdriverIO.Browser object
I've already tested with several urls and the result is always this error. Can you help me?